# Spring Security: Authentication results in HTTP 405 "Method not allowed"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

I use csrf in my code in spring-security.xml.
I think the problems are related with csrf.
All code is working but there are problems with login.jsp and spring-security.xml.
spring-security.xml looks like this:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/list" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/security" access="isAnonymous()"/>

    <form-login login-page="/security"
                  default-target-url="/list"
                  authentication-failure-url="/security?error"
                  username-parameter="username"
                  password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/security?logout"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>


<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

my LoginController look like this:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/security", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                         @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
                         Model model) {
        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid username or password");
        }
        if (logout != null) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", "You logout successfully");
        }

        return "login";
    }
}
```

This is my code in login.jsp:

```
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>
<div id="login-box">
    <h2>Insert Your Login and password:</h2>
    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>
    <form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/security'/>" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

When you open the page opens

[image]

but when I log in to the main page such error crashes such this

[image]

What should I fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is because you lack `login-processing-url`, which is the URL where Spring Login will trigger the authentication process.

Adding it via XML:

```
login-processing-url="/security"
```

Alternatively, if you do not wish to add it, make your form to send its POST request to `/login`, which is the default URL for Spring to trigger authentication (for Spring Security 4 and above).

See more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login).